# Cosa farai da o di grande?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Un mio amico (anche lui non-nativo) mi ha detto recentemente che in italiano non si dice "Cosa hai fatto **di** grande" ma "Cosa hai fatto **da** grande". È vero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sono due frasi corrette ma di senso differente:

> Cosa hai fatto di grande

pone un quesito su cosa sia stato fatto di importante

Esempio:

> Cosa hai fatto di grande per meritare la medaglia al valor civile?

Invece la frase:

> Cosa hai fatto da grande

Si riferisce a cosa si è fatto in età avanzata, ossia quando una persona diventa grande

Esempio:

> Cosa hai fatto da grande per sentirti così maturo?

Un'ultima osservazione, rispetto al titolo della tua domanda, ossia

> Cosa farai da grande

In tal senso è giusto usare `da` in quanto ci si pone la domanda, cosa farai quando sarai diventato grande (di età). È una domanda che, ad esempio, un insegnante pone ai propri studenti per capire le ambizioni di ognuno.